# reStructuredText and glossary terms translation

Tags: internationalization, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, glossary

I'd like to know how can I translate (as in i18n) the terms in glossary. I use Sphinx 1.1.3

Let's say I have:

```
.. glossary::

   term
       definition
```

After I run `make gettext` I get the .po files but I can only translate the definitions, not the terms. I searched the documentation throughout but couldn't find any hints. If translation of terms is somehow possible, how can I automatically sort them alphabetically in target language?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that [this feature will be available in Sphinx 1.2](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx/issue/1090/gettext-does-not-extract-glossary-terms)

The question about sorting the translated glossary still remains. `:sorted:` does not work.